# How do I achieve this array-like layout?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

This is a bit from Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*:

[image]

I like the format of that centered portion, and I wonder how it's achieved. I doubt it's an array or a tikz commutative diagram, because how would I get the arrow to go inside the cell like that?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 7):

The output uses [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)' extensible `\xmapsto`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\[
  \varphi 
  \xmapsto{\makebox[.35\linewidth]{\raisebox{.5\baselineskip}{$
    \Hom_R(M \otimes_R N, P) \cong
    \{ \text{Bilinear maps $M \times N$ to $P$} \}
  $}}}
  \varphi b.
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \Hom(M & \otimes_R N, P)\simeq \bigl\{\text{Bilinear maps }M & & \times N\enspace \text{to}\enspace P\bigr\}\\
     & \;\varphi \mathrel{\mathrlap{\xmapsto{\hspace{11.65em}}}}  &  & \varphi b
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]